# Is it possible to manipulate FindFit

Tags: manipulate

I was wondering if it is possible to manipulate a `FindFit[]` function. As a basic example, if I had an equation $ax^2+bx+c$ and a set of data, would it be possible to manipulate the `c` value, while *Mathematica* outputs the best fit values for `a` and `b` for that `c` value?

Comment: Yes, just use an explicit value for c in the model you provide to FindFit.

Comment: One can theoretically `Manipulate` any expression.  But see the [`SynchronousUpdating`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html#1390557486) option to `Manipulate` for handling expressions that take a long time to compute.

Answer (score 5):

Extending @bills answer a little further:

```
p = Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}];

Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot@p, Plot[y /. FindFit[p, y = a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b}, x], {x, 1, 20}, 
                       Evaluated -> True]], 
{c, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
 p = Table[Prime[x], {x, 20}]; 
 Manipulate[FindFit[p, a x^2 + b x + c, {a, b}, x], {c, -10, 10}]
```

[image]